# What may be the cause of this training loss curve in CNN?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision

I have trained a CNN for Image classification, but I get the loss curve as below, x-axis is epoch and y-axis is loss, Is it learning rate too large or too small? I just use Adam and the lr is 0.001.
[image: loss curve]

Answer (score 1):

Chances are your model is overfitting means it is learning patterns that is not generalised. Although decrease is training loss is good and it represent that your model is learning as no. of epoch increase but true representative of learning can be found by look validation loss curve.

To overcome overfitting you can add `Dropout` layer, which pick some hidden units randomly and set their weights to zero.Also it may be that you have less data to train.

There are several other things to learn about this topic.

Comment: How "clearly" can it be when OP is not even showing the validation loss curve?

Comment: Sorry. It was a bad assumption. I overlooked few cases.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the plot to show the validation loss curve also. You can only determine the fit of your model by simultaneously analysing both the validation and train curves.

You can read about how to analyse the curves here: https://machinelearningmastery.com/learning-curves-for-diagnosing-machine-learning-model-performance/